# Pop up new window or tab in Firefox on keyboard shortcut

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm working on a web app and I have a situation where I want to allow the user to press a keyboard shortcut to open something in a new tab or window. Obviously popup blockers can create problems here. I know they try to be intelligent by determining if the popup window was initiated from some sort of user interaction (click, keypress, etc...). Chrome seems to handle this fine, opening the new tab when pressing the keyboard shortcut, but Firefox blocks it.

I've tried a number of things, including pretty much all the solutions presented in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript) SO question, but nothing seems to work for FF. It works fine in FF if the function that pops up the new window is called from a click event handler, but not from a keyboard event handler. Question is, does anybody know of a way to make this work from a keyboard event in FF?

Here was my latest attempt to make it work (works with Chrome but not FF):

```
var $newTabEl = $('<div>');
$(document.body).append($newTabEl);
$newTabEl.click(function() {
  $(this).target = "_blank";
  window.open('/request/preview/requestId/' + data.get('id'));
  return false;
});
$newTabEl.click();
$newTabEl.remove();
```

Comment: Can you try .on("click", function ... And .trigger("click");

Comment: How would that be different from `$newTabEl.click();` ? That triggers the click event. Does it use a different mechanism?

Comment: Just tried it, no difference - Firefox still says it blocked the popup.

Comment: Btw $(this).attr("target","_blank") but likely no difference

Comment: Setting the target as a property seemed to work just fine, though that was just doing what was demonstrated in the SO question I linked to. However, I can just as well pass it as the second argument to `window.open()` - but yeah, no difference. It tries but FF blocks the popup.

Comment: Ah, yeah you must pass as parameter. setting the target on an arbitrary div will not work. How about a link? Makes more sense. Using an access key perhaps?

Comment: @Justin Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running into this exact same problem and can't find a solution anywhere...

Comment: No, unfortunately. I think it needs to be filed as a bug with Mozilla, but I haven't yet done so. All I've done to get by is I added a menu option for our users to click to open a new window so it's not initiated by a keyboard event, and of course, encourage them to allow popups from our site if they use a keyboard shortcut.